# Do I have to pay tax on cash my brother is paying me for my half interest in a shared house?

Tags: taxes

My father recently passed away. His house was paid off and it was willed to me and my brother 50/50. However, prior to him passing, he quit claimed the house to me and my brother, so it wouldn't go to probate. My question is: My brother is going to remain in the house and wants to pay me cash for my share that's owed to me. We agreed on $60,000, which he had a bank check made out to me. Will I have to pay taxes on this $60,000? It's not a gift obviously....Thanks, Jay B.

Comment: What country are you living in?

Comment: I'm lost, it's inherited, definitely not enough to qualify for estate tax. The house would sell for more I'm sure, but since he'll live there, pay the property taxes and such, I just said 60k would be fine. It's certainly not a gift, he's just paying me cash for my inheritance and I'm giving him my half interest in the house.

Comment: Jay/ Jason, why do you have 2 logins for SE? I will assume US unless you set me straight.

Comment: I spoke to a tax lawyer. He said that since the half I've settled on with my brother is less than my half of the fair narket value, I just have to claim it with IRS, but it would be considered a "Wash" under a capital gains/losses under Chapter D or something, but I wouldn't be taxed

Comment: This assumes you negate the results of the quit claim. You'll have to spend some more money on that attorney (or better - a proper tax adviser, CPA or EA licensed in your State. Attorneys usually suck at taxes, they only good for litigation/conflict resolution).

Comment: @littleadv - exactly. The lawyer may not have gotten the whole story. OP should review the link you suggested to understand how to do this right.

Answer (score 1):

When one is gifted a home, gifted, not bequeathed, the cost basis follows. i.e. The cost of the house, plus documented improvements, if any, is the basis of the house. Say it was $10K. Your half had a $5K basis, and you sold it for $60K. You owe tax on $55K profit. "Recently" implies less than a year, so this gain is short term, ordinary tax rate.

In theory, when the house was quit-claimed, a [Form 709](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f709.pdf) (gift tax) should have been filed. In reality, the $120K simply goes against his lifetime $5M+ and no tax due, and few know enough to file this form. I am sorry for your loss.

UPDATE - The article titled [Adjustments for certain gifts made within 3 years of decedent’s death](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/2035) suggests that there is a window of time that would negate the bad outcome I suggest. A nice way out, thanks to @littleadv for pointing this out. News to me.

Comment: I think there are rules that bring the gifts made shortly before death back into the estate.

Comment: @littleadv - ? If you can cite such a rule, you're welcome to edit it into my answer. I was unaware of such a rule. That would be good.

Comment: IRC Sec. 2035. http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/2035